# AEM content fragment graphQL, query all parent fragments that includes given content path

Tags: json, graphql, content-management-system, aem, crx

Bascially, what I need is , given a content path, e.g let's say a piece of content fragment built by Product Model.
[image]

Then I have another content fragement (let's say it is parent content fragement) built by a diff model called 'PageBody' , this parent content fragement includes that product content fragment.
[image]

Now I wish to build a graphql query, to retrieve all/any parents content fragement JSON  that includes this product
[image]

graphql query:

```
query itemRefByPath($path:String!){
  productByPath (_path: $path) {
    item{
      _path
    }
    
    _references {
      ... on ProductModel {
        __typename
        _path        
      }
      ... on PageRef {
        _path
      }
      ... on PageModel {
        _path
      }
      
      ... on PageBodyModel {
        _path
      }
      
      ... on TabModel {
        _path
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But as you can see, the references I got empty...
Anyone could advise me what I have done wrong? Guess my graphql syntax got issue right?
Please provide me some sample query code to help
Thanks

Comment: You're trying to query by _path. The _path of child and parent can't be same. I would suggest putting in the schema of both and then asking your question

Comment: @ShivamSahil Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to query by _path. The _path of child and parent can't be same. I would suggest putting in the schema of both and then asking your question